# Stata: replace missing values with the values from observations with same ID number

Tags: dataset, stata, survey

I am using population-level American Community Survey data to look at factors that affect income from self-employment, with a primary interest in the female population. I want to create a variable to measure "husband's income." There is a variable `pincp` that measures a person's total income, and dummy variables I created for `married` and `female`. All households are linked by a unique identifier `serialno`. I am using Stata.

Universe: population age 18 and older whose primary job is self-employment. Must have earned at least $1000 from self-employment in past year, and under the 95th percentile for self-employed earnings.

Assuming that a married male in a household represents a husband**,

```
gen husb_income = pincp if female==0 & married==1
```

How do I copy the value of `husb_income` for other observations with the same `serialno`? If there is an (employed) married man in a household, I want `husb_income` to reflect his income for all observations pertaining to that household.

** I know that this is a gratuitous assumption; I'm not concerned with that right now.

Comment: This question seems off-topic for this site. Try Stack Overflow and post any attempt you've made in form of code.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with something like

```
egen husb_income = total( pincp*(female==0)*(married==1) ), by(serialno)
```

If that's too rough, you would want to create more detailed code using something like

```
bysort serialno (female) : gen husb_income = pincp[1] * (_N == 2) * (female==0)
```

for nuclear families with just the husband and wife. If you are not familiar with these constructs, you should read about them in the manual and Nick Cox' column (http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004).

ACS data have detail linkages between family members, so you should be able to identify exactly who the husband is of the female in question using these linkages.

Comment: Some discussion of technique at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0043

Answer (score 1):

Keep the cases that are of the married male, drop all variables except `serialno` and `pincp`. Rename `pincp` to `husb_income`. Save it as a separate data set.

Now, open the original data set, use `merge` command to merge the husband data back:

```
use originalData, replace
merge m:1 serialno using c:\temp\whateverTheHusbandFileIsCalled
```

---

Also, you may have more than 2 married males in the same household. If that happens, the above command will not work because it will become a many-to-many merging. In that case, you'd have to generate an extra couple indicator and incorporate that into the `merge` statement as an identifier right next to `serialno`.